# Creating a Dynamic Image using Friends pictures

Tags: php, facebook, image

I am working on a Facebook for which I need to get all the Profile Pictures of Friends of the users. Which I did using FQL query. I need these images for creating a poster of all the Friends Profile pics along tags in them.

For that I need to create a Dynamic poster for every user with their Friends tagged in them.

I tried using the GD Library for PHP.

I tried with the imagecreatefromjpeg() function of php for which I can use one image and pass it to the main image. But here I have more than 1 images (average about 100 images) depending on the number of friends the user has.

What function do I need to create this dynamic poster ?
Please any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this http://devzone.zend.com/29/dynamic-image-generation-with-php/